# Numeric value to date and hour in r

Tags: r

I have got a value like : 1.566940e+12
which needs to be converted to a date format like 2019-10-06 and an hour on 24 hour scale. I would like to use the anytime package

Comment: How does that number convert to a datetime?

Comment: Try with `date_decimal` from `lubridate`

Comment: What about something like `as.POSIXct(1.566940e+12/3600, origin = "1970-01-01")`?

Comment: Number of seconds since? What is the origin?

Comment: Or maybe it is the number of seconds times 1000 (in which case replace 3600 with 1000 in @Jaap's comment)?  Also might need to use the `tz = "GMT"` argument depending on what time zone is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this number is in milliseconds.

Using anytime, this is as easy:

`anytime::anytime(x = 1.566940e+12/1000)`

this is what I get:

> "2019-08-27 23:06:40 CEST"

If you specifically want to see only date and hour, you can do so with:

`format(anytime::anytime(x = 1.566940e+12/1000), "%Y-%m-%d %H")`

> "2019-08-27 23"